# How to remove down votes?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, downvotes

I have seen some Question/Answers which get annihilated with down votes in a couple of seconds, after a quick edit the Question/Answer then begins to make sense and is a valid Question/Answer where the user is seeking help or trying to provide an answer.

**Is it possible to flag a Question/Answer to an Administrator whom can then remove down-votes?** Even appealing to the voters to remove their down votes after a Question/Answer has be edited and improved is not possible as the votes are locked in.

Not being able to improve your Question/Answer score then leads to duplicate Questions or the deletion of a good Answer.

Edit:

---

As suggest by @gnat in the comments below (I get it.): I would like to state that i understand the flaws in this question and my mind has been changed. I do agree with the answer marked as correct.

Comment: If a post has been edited, votes become unlocked.

Comment: Would like to see reason for these down votes? Follow the leader Parana voting.

Comment: @AndrewArnold Thanks i did not know that.

Comment: Another (more likely) reason for the downvotes? The question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Comment: see [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773) at MSE

Comment: @Pomster I wonder how you got that much rating without any questions/answers beside this one ?

Comment: I just up-voted this taking it from -17 to -16, likely because you have been trolled by down-voters. I would like down-voting either completely removed or make it so that when a down-vote is offered the down-voter must be identified and [MUST give an explanation] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes), instead of cowardly down-voting without explanation. Often down-voting is done because people are too lazy to read a question properly or out of spite. If we must have down-voting, then at least with counter-arguments, instead of a dumb mouse click.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Even appealing to the voters to remove their down votes after a Question/Answer has be edited and improved is not possible as the votes are locked in.

If the voters voted before the edit, then their votes are no longer locked in, because the edit should unlock them. There is no mechanism for straightforwardly appealing to voters though. Nor is it generally desirable to have one.

> Is it possible to flag a Question/Answer to an Administrator whom can then remove down-votes?Is it possible to flag a Question/Answer to an Administrator whom can then remove down-votes?

No, there is no provision for arbitrarily removing votes. Votes get annulled in the case of fraud but normally downvoting a question that one finds flawed is not a case of fraud. If you think about it, how would a moderator decide that my downvote *should* be removed? Maybe the question was improved but maybe I still find it to be unclear, or to suffer from some other flaw that *still* warrants a downvote. Why should my downvote be removed if the question is still terrible? My vote is tied to my evaluation of the question, and should be changed only if *I* decide that it should be changed.

Comment: Thanks i agree with what you have said here.

Comment: Interestingly -- or horrifyingly -- admin removal of votes was also metioned [by Tim Post recently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269510/) (link is 10k only).

Answer (score 5):

No, there won't be anyone for you to flag to remove the downvotes of others just because you think the post shouldn't have been down voted, or no longer merits downvotes.