# Can we have a tool for viewing posts we've down voted that were subsequently edited?

Tags: feature-request, voting

I came across [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272676/916299) on meta that talks about the barrage of down votes that posts can receive, which, after an edit or two become good questions and answers.

The problem exists however, that the voters will often never return to the post they voted on and their votes are subsequently reasonably unfair.

Is it unreasonable to have, as a privilege perhaps, a list of posts which I have voted on and which were then edited so that I can review my votes?

---

### Design

My initial thought of design would be similar to the review screens, where clicking any of the blue buttons removes the post from any sort of queue, not to be shown again until another edit is made.

[image]

---

### Other Questions<sup>1</sup>

[This meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196228/171964) outlines the same problem, but hinges on using [DSE](http://data.stackexchange.com), which isn't possible as votes are anonymous. True, but votes are only anonymous *publically*. Votes are certainly attributed privately otherwise multiple votes would be possible and access to your votes tab on your profile would not.

I'd missed [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/171964) on SE meta and unfortunately it is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) but, reading through that page now, I can't find a clear answer why it was rejected. However, I'm encouraged by the *proportion* of users that support this idea. For just 402 views, 63 upvotes and 1 down vote. Perhaps this time, the SE team will be more accommodating.

[image]

<sup>1. Thanks for the extra reading ChrisF♦ :D</sup>

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196228/list-my-downvoted-posts-that-were-edited and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c

Comment: This should be a prominent feature on our profile page. I would much prefer this to the "How close are you to your next reinforcement biscuit?" that features so prominently now.

Comment: Very good suggestion - I've felt for a long time that the few users who do actually edit their question for the better are probably disillusioned from the site due to the fact that their questions are (probably) never re-opened, despite them doing exactly what we've just told them to do.

Comment: maybe it'd suffice to have appropriate syntax in advanced search to find them.

Comment: Yeah, i see downvotes as a red flag that i need to improve my answer (and i do edit alot), but it could be nice to have feedback on thoses edits aswell.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but I just downvote and then add the question to my favorites.

Comment: Maybe also include a filter that makes sure the post was not downvoted too much after the edit.

Comment: Also related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/notification-on-edit-of-downvoted-content and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346126/how-to-know-when-a-downvoted-question-has-been-improved?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This userscript: [Get a list of posts you've voted on that have been edited](https://stackapps.com/q/6755/29529) will do basically what you're asking for.

Answer (score 130):

I think the main opposition to measures like these in the past was that the suggested UI would have been noisy and/or distracting to long time users.

I haven't been around that long, but I've already downvoted more than 500 posts, if I started getting inbox notifications each time one was edited I would find it irritating pretty quickly...

The suggestion here looks like it would be a little less noisy, but it would be a pretty major build for the SE team.

I would suggest adding an indication that the post was edited to the votes tab in the user activity tab. Something like:

[image]

Just adding "(edited)" after the post link probably wouldn't require a huge amount of development time, it wouldn't be noisy, and it would allow users to easily check for edits on posts they downvoted.

Comment: I don't mind this. It's certainly not very noisy, though I would add the option to upvotes too.

Comment: `but it would be a pretty major build for the SE team` - they've been adding loads to the review pages recently. Now is a great time to add a tool like this; they are already in the mindset.

Comment: @JamesWebster That may be true, but personalized review queues would be new-ish territory.

Comment: (nod) That's a pretty critical difference I missed.

Comment: In the context of our discussion, the meaning of `(edited)` is pretty clear.  But for someone who randomly browses to that section, it could be interpretted as "You edited this in addition to downvoting" or "The user edited this at some point(not necesarily after you downvoted".  So I would consider `(user edited since)` or something similar if someone has a better wording.  I considered `(user edited May 19)` but the left hand dates never have a year even when a year has past, and so the relative difference between the vote date and the edit date could sometimes be confusing. But great idea.

Comment: Is it common for people to edit posts that were downvoted long long ago?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard It is common enough, I do it once in a while when I'm researching something.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231200/217863

Comment: I like this -- it could maybe help promote re-open votes on closed questions.  Seeing an "edited"/"re-opened" flag would allow me to go back and remove any now-irrelevant comments and/or votes on answers based on the edits performed.

Comment: The list should be sorted by activity. (Edits bump to the top.)

Answer (score 24):

This is the same kind of issue that triggered me to make [a badge suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71440/badge-suggestion-responsive-aka-quality-control-adaptability-etc) some time ago.

I suggested that there should be a badge for editing your own posts such that previous down-voters then changed their vote to an up-vote.

In the discussion that followed, it was also suggested that there should be a badge for changing your votes in light of good edits.

The suggestion was made quite a long time ago now. It got a lot of votes, but as far as I know it never went any further than that. But I do still feel that the behaviour I've described above is worth incentivizing, and badges would help to do that.

Comment: "a badge for changing your votes in light of good edits" could cause some problematic voting/gaming.

Comment: @apaul34208 - yes it could. One would need to think about how to mitigate that kind of thing when designing the system. I'm confident that it could be done. But having said that, there are already plenty of ways to game the system if one really wanted to.

Comment: I like the original idea "Made an edit to ones own post that resulted in people removing their down-votes", seems more productive and the risk of accruing downvotes that aren't later reversed would mitigate gaming.

Comment: Yes, I agree, my original suggestion would be much the easier part to implement. (but it wouldn't answer this question)

Comment: Even without a badge, you'd get 1 rep point each time you removed a down vote, so there is some incentive to do so.

Answer (score 2):

For those posts where I have any hope of redemption, I usually leave a comment describing what should be improved. I then periodically use the "all activities" view in my profile to find the questions I have commented upon.

Comment: That shows how conscientious you are, but it shouldn't require work on your part to find these posts. It should be as easy as finding recent activity, period, without having to tag them (there is lots of crappy content that I would not use your strategy because someone already has made a good comment, so tagging it just so I can come back to it would just increase the noise: those are the comments I upvote instead of repeating).

Comment: @meriton, This is the task I want to automate.

Comment: Going through the comments is infeasible for some of us. The interesting comments are covered by a landfill of canned responses from the review queues.

Answer (score -8):

I like the idea very much, but I don't like the suggested solutions.

[apaul34208's idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294602/2302862) would probably require one to search though pages and pages of downvotes.
It would at least have to be a list with the new edits on top.
But even such a list would probably be forgotten by most, and I think users should actively be made aware of such edits.

Now, you certainly can't receive an inbox alert for *every* edit on a post you downvoted, that would probably even overflow SO's database.
There's also users who save their edits every 10 seconds or so, who already make me mad when I'm reading their posts.

But if there was a way to tell *relevant* edits apart from irrelevant ones, then I think it would be reasonable to receive inbox notifications.

---

First, I think once a post has not been edited for a certain amount of time (I suggest 7 days), subsequent edits should never again trigger inbox notifications for downvoters.

Second, inbox notifications should not be triggered by edits themselves, but rather by the first vote on the post after an edit, if that vote is an upvote.

And third, if an edit should only be eligible to trigger inbox notifications if it changed a certain amount of characters (I suggest 100) and

1. either changes more content than it adds,
2. or adds so much content that the added content is now more than 50%.

---

This would lock away edits on old posts, minor edits, edits that expand bad posts with more (presumably bad) content instead of changing the existing one, and edits after which the post still receives downvotes.

A lot of edited-to-good posts would probably still be left out this way, but rather that than spamming users with notifications or not notifying them at all.

Comment: I think this is more complicated than it needs to be. Having lots of posts to go through isn't a problem because they don't have to be done all at once (or even at all), that's a similar problem to the Close Votes queue.

Comment: Though I agree with not sending inbox alerts. I wouldn't send any alerts.

Comment: Isn't the amount of edits that actually turn a bad post into a good one a vast minority? If every user had their own "review votes" queue where 95% of all edits turn out to make no difference, they would stop going to that queue, wouldn't they? I think edits have to be filtered somehow.

Comment: I still disagree. Those users who make lots of votes are the active users anyway are probably not going to worry about reviewing a max of 40 posts per day.

Comment: A max of 40? Where does that limit come from? Does changing or clearing a vote count into the voting limit too? And even if it does, if 95% of edits *do not* improve the post enough to make it actually good, it would take 800 questions to get those 40 votes out. It would be like the H&I queue, where you can help 1 in a 100 posts, which makes it feel like a waste of time, sadly.

Comment: I'm referring to the [40 votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes) [per day cap](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254453/increase-max-daily-votes). You could accumulate a back log of reviews of course.