# How to know when a downvoted question has been improved?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes

When I downvote a question, it's to help the questioner understand there is something wrong with it. If the questioner then goes back an improves the question, I should remove my downvote. However, I don't know when this edit has been made.

I would like to receive a notification when a post I have downvoted has been edited, so I can go back and change my vote.

Comment: I use my comment history for this purpose, allows me to quickly go back to questions I figured were possible to save (which is the only occasion I would choose to comment next to downvoting). Assuming you don't comment-spam the site, this makes any notification system not worth the time IMO.

Comment: `When I downvote a question, it's to help the questioner understand there is something wrong with it.` But that's not the primary purpose of downvotes.  The primary purpose of downvotes is to inform all future readers of the post that it's problematic.  If the user uses this as motivation to improve the post, that's just a nice side effect.

Comment: I don't know if I want my inbox flooded with emails from posts where my vote is now unlocked, but I do think there should be some sort of icon on your vote history page where you can easily see if a vote is locked or not.

Comment: Already asked some years ago [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252055/460775) and [here, but declined almost 7 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/155051).

Comment: I sometimes leave a comment explaining why I downvoted it. If OP responds to it after improving I go back to the question and cancel my downvote (of necessary). This applies to answers as well.

Comment: [Kind of related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339034/summary-of-downvoted-answers-which-have-changed-and-are-not-deleted). Inbox notification seems to be a tick to much imho. But some register card would be nice. It is good, if we have userscripts temporarly. But we still need it native in the long run.

Comment: This question is not really Stack Overflow specific and probably fits better on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @TotZam It's [already there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/230261). MSO works, too, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A few of things you could do:

1. Favourite / Star questions that you might want to go back to, you can then view them and sort them by activity. Obviously this would require some maintenance on your part to keep the list relevant.

[Your sorted favourites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3364648/beanfrog?tab=favorites&sort=activity)

2. Review the downvotes you have placed at regular intervals, say once a day, it wouldn't take too long to go through the list if you did it regularly.

[Downvotes you have placed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3364648/beanfrog?tab=votes&sort=downvote)

3. You could also comment on a post to say something like *"As it stands it's difficult to answer this question, please do X, Y and Z and reply to me and I will revisit this question later."*, thus giving the OP an avenue to get back in touch with you.

Regardless of this, you have no obligation to go back to questions you have voted on, but the sentiment is honourable. I think you're expecting a lot from users that post bad questions, as I rarely find that many posts I downvote are edited significantly enough.

Comment: On 3 - as usual add comments to your downvotes at your own risk. Please don't come back to Meta asking "why I'm getting revenge downvotes when I suggested improvements on downvoted question"... Consider if doing just one is more suitable for your sanity.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Revenge downvoting is a serious problem, but people not knowing what the problem is with the post is also bad. It seems like there's no easy solution. A question with a downvote and no comments wouldn't really give much insight for me as a reader. If I searched and found the post, it's usually at least somewhat "useful"; sometimes dupes and dead ends are helpful, [e.g. sometimes I deliberately search for things I know to be wrong/impossible to try to research common misunderstandings.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590978/reference-of-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 28):

You can install the "[Show Edited Votes](https://stackapps.com/questions/6755/get-a-list-of-posts-youve-voted-on-that-have-been-edited)" user script. It adds a "edited since voting" sub-tab to your "votes" tab:

[image: edited since voting]

Selecting the sub-tab will show all posts which have been edited since you voted on them, and displays if the vote was a down-vote or an up-vote.

---

<sup>Note: When I originally posted this the author had not yet obtained an SE API key, which significantly limited the number of times you could use this script in a day. A few hours after I posted this answer, the author obtained an API key, so that is no longer an issue.</sup>

Comment: Still wondering why such good userscripts get no native support. This should be implemented.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Native support not needed since there are already such good userscripts. :)

Comment: I am not sure if this was sarcasm or not @JasonC =) Userscripts need to be installed on every machine, error prone on siteupdates, I need an extension in my browser for it, which makes it slower and less secure. List can go on.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Not sarcasm. If you're running into performance / security issues with Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey, by the way, you should report it to them on their issue trackers. PS Browse around on http://stackapps.com, there's a whole *world* of great stuff there!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I want my inbox flooded with emails from posts where my vote is now unlocked, but I do think there should be some sort of icon on the vote history page where you can easily see if a vote is locked or not.

Here is a rough sketch of my idea:

> [image: vote lock indicator]

Obviously the icon would need to be something that fits with the other Stack Exchange icons. I just used the first lock/unlock icons I found.

Other variations of this idea would also work.

- Show just the lock icon, and leave a blank space if it is unlocked.
- Use the same lock icon for locked and unlocked, and just have it set to light gray if it is unlocked.
- Instead of using icons, changing the color of an already existing element might also work.
- Use a different icon instead of the lock, but has the same meaning.